# Clarification on divisibility of quotient rings regarding polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

If I am given a quotient ring $F_q[x]/p(x)$, with $p(x)$ being some polynomial, then the number of elements in $F_q[x]/p(x)$ divisible by a polynomial $h(x)$ is simply the number of multiples of $h(x)$ in the format $f(x)h(x)$, with $f(x) \in \mathbb{F_q[x]}$ such that $\deg(f(x)h(x)) < \deg p(x)$, correct?

For example, the set of elements of $\mathbb{F_2}[x]/(x^4 + x^3 + 1)$ that are divisible by $x^2 + 1$ has $4$ elements: $\{0(x^2 + 1), 1(x^2 + 1), x(x^2 + 1)\}, (x + 1)(x^2 + 1)\}$ since all the elements of this set have degree less than $4$, correct?

A follow-up clarification that I was wondering is that how does whether or not $F_q[x]/p(x)$ is a field impact how many of its elements are divisible by a polynomial $h(x)$, if there is any impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think does not makes sense to say $h(x)$ divides elements of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/p(x)$ because if you take $2$ polynomials in the same class, then one of the two polynomials can be divided by $h(x)$ while the other one no.

For example if you take $h(x)=x+1$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/x^2$, then

$x+1$ is divided by $x+1$ but $x^2+x+1$ is not divided by $x+1$ and they are in the same class modulo $x^2$.

In general you can ask to divide wrt the class of $h(x)$ modulo $p(x)$.

If $t(x)h(x)$ has degree less than $p(x)$, then $t(x)h(x)$ is a multiple of $h(x)$ in the quotient ring.

Suppose $t(x)h(x)$ has degree greater than $p(x)$. Then

$t(x)h(x)=\alpha(x)p(x)+\beta(x)$

Then $\beta$ could not be a multiple of $h(x)$ but it’s class modulo $p(x)$ yes.

For example $x  $ is not divisible by $x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ but it’s so in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/x^2$. In fact

$x\equiv x^2+x \equiv x(x+1) \mod p(x)=x^2$

Note that you have your requirement if and only if $h(x)$ divides $p(x)$

Comment: In the statement "If t(x)h(x) has degree less than h(x), then t(x)h(x) is a multiple of h(x) in the quotient ring.", did you mean to say "If t(x)h(x) has degree less than p(x)"?

Comment: @FernandoTorres uhhh, thank you ahaha